# Adding Social Extensions to Google Ad Words

Tags: google, google-ads, social-media, google-plus

I have viewed several videos that describe how to add G+ to Google Ad Words' ad extensions.  The issue is that in 2015, there is no "Add Social Extensions" option under the Add Extensions tab.  Can anyone explain where/how to add G+ as an Google Ad Word extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Your ads can be eligible to show social extensions without any setup if they meet the following requirements**:
>
> Your Google+ page: **Your Google+ page has to be linked to your website and have a significant number of followers, meaning a minimum of 100 for most companies**. Follow these instructions to link your Google+ page and your website if they aren't already linked. This will allow social extensions to appear, and it'll also help your Google+ page and website be discovered in Google search.
>
> Your ad's landing page: **The domain of your ad's display URL has to match the website URL you've added to your Google+ page**.
>   For example, an ad that has a URL of www.happysnacks.com/low-carb will match with a Google+ page that displays the website URL of www.happysnacks.com because they share the same domain.
>   If you have the same site with different top-level or second-level domains for different countries, contact us and ask us to match these. For example, your ads lead to google.fr and google.co.uk, but your Google+ page displays the URL google.com

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722132?hl=en

What you can do by hand is activating the Review Social Extension. For that, you can simply set up a profile on Google My Business, then activate the Reviews ad extension.